# Ant exec executable to execute PL/SQL procedure fails

Tags: jenkins, ant, exec, executable, sqlplus

I have an Ant script to execute SQL and PL/SQL procedures.

```
<exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" >         
  <arg value="${user}/${password}@${DB}" />
  <arg value="@${scriptFilename}" />
</exec>
```

The above code executes SQL scripts and packages, but not procedures like:

```
BEGIN
   -- drop functions
   FOR R IN (
      SELECT owner, object_name
      FROM all_objects
      WHERE owner='FCPOTP'
      AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION'))
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop function '||R.owner||'.'||R.object_name; 
   END LOOP;  
   -- drop procedure
   FOR R IN (
      SELECT owner, object_name
      FROM all_objects
      WHERE owner='FCPOTP'
      AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE'))
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure '||R.owner||'.'||R.object_name; 
   END LOOP;     
END;
```

How can I use the same `exec sqlplus` executables for executing everything?

Comment: How does it 'fail' - what errors do you get? Is that really part of a procedure, or an anonymous block; and what happens if you run than manually through SQL\*Plus?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I didn't receive any error. But the block is not executed. It simply says    [exec] Connected to:
     [exec] Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
     [exec] With the Partitioning option
     [exec] 
     [exec]  36  Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
     [exec] With the Partitioning option
     [echo] ===== End =====
     [echo]

Comment: It would be better to show that output in the question so it can be formatted properly. But I get the gist of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get an error and from the output in a comment you don't see the block being executed. That's because it isn't. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663):

> SQL*Plus stores the subprograms you enter in the SQL buffer. Execute the current subprogram with a RUN or slash (/) command. A semicolon (;) is treated as part of the PL/SQL subprogram and will not execute the command.

At the moment your anonymous block (subprogram) is being entered into the 'SQL buffer', but is never being executed.

You just need to add a `/` to your script file, after your anonymous block:

```
...
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure '||R.owner||'.'||R.object_name; 
   END LOOP;     
END;
/
```

Comment: After adding the / the procedure is executed successfully. Thank you.